# Icon to tell listener that answering the question would make a harmful sound

Tags: icons, accessibility, visual-design, graphic-design

I have a speech impairment (when I pronounce most letters 'S' they cause harm to the listener). I need an icon to be able to hold up, to a listener, who presumably knows either me or the icon, that means:

I cannot answer your question, verbally, because answering it out add I am currently thinking, would produce an annoying sound.

(I want to avoid these sounds because they would disrupt both the speaker and the listener).

Th.x.

Comment: Jack, your best bet is NOT an icon, but a message explaining this situation. There's no icon for a condition with this degree of specificity  that can be understood by everyone

Answer (score 1):

Would a "hush" icon make sense?

Something like https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hush-emoticon-15882081.jpg

[image]